# Dynamic algorithm to find length of longest alternating sequence

Tags: algorithm

LetA=〈a1, . . . , an〉be a sequence of numbers where n >0 and each number ai∈{0,1}.  A subsequence〈ai1, . . . , aik〉of A is a sequence of elements such that i1<···< ik and 1≤k≤n.  A subsequenceofAis an alternating sequence if each element is different than the one preceding it.  For example, letA=〈0,1,0,0,0,1,0〉then〈0〉,〈1〉,〈0,1〉,〈1,0〉and〈0,1,0,1,0〉are different alternating subsequenceswhile〈1,1〉is not an alternating subsequence.  The longest alternating subsequence of A is〈0,1,0,1,0〉and it has length 5.

(a)  Design  an O(n^2)  dynamic  programming  algorithm  to  find  the  length  of  the  longest  alternating subsequence of a given sequence A

(b)  Design  an O(n)  dynamic  programming  algorithm  to  find  the  length  of  the  longest  alternating subsequence of a given sequence A.

Comment: Designing a O(n) algorithm is easy (count the number of transitions, but not DP?). Designing a O(n^2) algorithm seems much more difficult here

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need a DP solution for this.

Greedy-approach works in the most straight-forward way for this.
To summarize: since the list only contains `[0,1]`, you just need to check how many times to the values change in the sequence; and thats your length of the maximum-alternating-subsequence.

#### Time-complexity: O(N)

Here is the working code:

```
count = 1
ll = [0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
lval = ll[0]
for item in ll[1:]:
    if item != lval:
        count += 1
        lval = item

print(count)
```

Output:

```
5
```

### EDIT

If you are still looking for a DP solution, here is the O(N) solution:

**D[i][j] represents the length of the maximum-alternating-subsequence until index `i` whose last-value is `j`**

```
ll = [0,1,0,0,0,1,0]

D = [[0,0] for _ in range(len(ll))]

D[0][0] = 1 if ll[0] == 0 else 0
D[0][1] = 1 - D[0][0]

for i in range(1, len(ll)):
    D[i][ll[i]] = max(1 + D[i-1][1-ll[i]], D[i-1][ll[i]])
    D[i][1-ll[i]] = D[i-1][1-ll[i]]

print(max(D[-1]))ll = [0,1,0,0,0,1,0]

D = [[0,0] for _ in range(len(ll))]

D[0][0] = 1 if ll[0] == 0 else 0
D[0][1] = 1 - D[0][0]

for i in range(1, len(ll)):
    D[i][ll[i]] = max(1 + D[i-1][1-ll[i]], D[i-1][ll[i]])
    D[i][1-ll[i]] = D[i-1][1-ll[i]]

print(max(D[-1]))
```